# Modulous for a non-0 based range of numbers

Tags: javascript, ascii

I'm trying to manipulate the ASCII code for a given string of letters (all caps). In the example below, I increment the ASCII code by one and output it to `#newText`.

```
<h2 id="text">ABCXYZ</h2>
<h2 id="newText">placeholder</h2>

var text = document.getElementById("text").firstChild.nodeValue;
var newText = "";

for (i=0; i < text.length; i++){
  newText = newText + String.fromCharCode(text.charCodeAt(i)+1);
}

document.getElementById("newText").firstChild.nodeValue = newText;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/gg9Hx/19/

The problem is that Z is changed into a [. (This makes sense, since the ASCII range for A-Z is 65-90, and [ has an ASCII value of 91.) Instead, I want Z to transform into A.

I've tried modulus to get the ASCII values to wrap around, but I'm having difficulty with the non-0 range of ASCII values.

If `x = 91;`, then `console.log(((x-65)%26)+65);` results in 65, which is fine. But if `x = 64;` then the same formula results in 64, when I want it to to be 90.

How can I account for the non-zero range of the capital letters' ASCII values when incrementing and modulating them? In this example, I'd like to transform 91 into 65, 92 into 66, 93 into 67, 64 into 90, 63 into 89, and 62 into 88 as examples.

Comment: How about just `if (x=91) {x=65} else if (x=64) {x=90}`

Comment: I think that'd be pretty crazy to write for all 26 cases. Also, it's not very flexible if I need to shift the letters by something other than +1 in the future.

Comment: It would be an issue with more shifting, but why would you have 26 cases when just working with A-Z and shifting one place, it's either just one above or one below ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pad `x` with another `26` to handle values within 26 below 65.

```
console.log(((x+26-65)%26)+65);
```

If you need more padding, just add some other multiple of 26.

Comment: @ndh - This solves the heart of the problem which was how to handle modulus with non-0 ranged numbers. 38 is not a valid input (capital simple letters only), but I can always `toUpper()` for production.

Comment: To be clear, the solution for any character as low as zero (or however low you want) is in the last sentence. For example, if you wanted to be certain to go as low as `0`, you'd add `+78` instead of `+26`.

Comment: Thanks cookiemonster, I understood your solution before and only wanted to make it clear to KatieK that your specific answer isn't complete, as it doesn't work for all integer values. She might think that since 64 now works, all integers must work. I didn't mean to challenge the correctness of the general answer but emphasize that adding just one multiple might not be enough. Btw, the +78-65 or just +13 is probably ideal for @KatieK's specific problem. Also, I concede that adeneo's answer wasn't the best answer because it was superfluous, without benefits to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `A-Z` is 26 characters so do your arithmetic modulo 26. Then encode the result (0...25) as the desired character range, which in this case is as simple as adding 65.

Similarly to decode, first convert from the character range to numbers and then apply arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a condition to see if the number is lower than 65 or higher than 90, then just do the opposite of what you're currently doing for numbers over 90

```
var x = text.charCodeAt(i)+1;
    x = x > 90 ? ((x-65)%26)+65 : x < 65 ? (((x+65)%26)+65) : x;
    newText = newText + String.fromCharCode(x);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gg9Hx/20/)

To make it work with any number, use

```
x = x > 90 ? x-(Math.ceil((x-90)/26)*26) : x < 65 ? x+(Math.ceil((65-x)/26)*26) : x;
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer, but I want anybody reading this to note that this method does not work for arbitrary numbers. The only reason it works is because -65 = 65 (mod 26)

Comment: @ndh - You're right, I just took the modulus stuff from the question, but looking at it more closely it's just a really complicated way of writing `if (x > 90) x = x-26` etc

Comment: Or more in line with my answer, it would equal `x = x > 90 ? x-26 : x < 65 ? x+26 : x;`

Comment: After some fiddling around, the solution seems to be `x = x > 90 ? x - (Math.ceil((x-90)/26)*26) : x < 65 ? x + (Math.ceil(26/x) * 26) : x;`

Comment: I'm sorry for my inconsistency, but I take back my comment about it being a nice solution. Your answer is nice if there are indeed these conditions for it to work correctly, but there are not. The only inhibitor for Katie's original solution to work is if x is smaller than 65, making a negative modulus. Assuming that x is greater than 0, a complete solution would be x=(x+13)%26+65. This way, the modulus is never negative. If x can be any integer, then you would have to add a multiple of 26 until the part inside the parentheses is positive.

Comment: Your alternative solution is useful, and I think should be changed to the main answer, as long as you replace (26/x) with ((65-x)/26)

Comment: @ndh - Nope, no problem! Some of us think it's fun to play with this stuff even if an answer is already accepted, and I agree with you. I got it right on the first one, and for some reason instead of just doing opposite, as in `(65-x)/26` I just typed in `26/x` and it probably worked in my limited testing as I didn't notice it.

Answer (score -1):

You have the first part of the solution, `console.log(((x-65)%26)+65);`. As you noticed, it works in some cases but not others. So use it in the cases where it works and use something else in the other cases. Just write code that does what you want.